# How to share a few specific elements of a page only

Tags: facebook, share, element, product

I have a page of products on my website with a share button on each, now how can I tell facebook to automatically select the title and image of the product shared rather than the whole page.

[A link to my site](http://www.fancydressclothing.net/categories/49/1950s-Costumes.html)

The site is written using php on smarty type script with tpl files,

ps i dont really know php very well.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

A server side scripting language would be the easiest:

in php you could share the page + an extra variable , then if your page detects this variable you can set specific meta data.

http://www.fancydressclothing.net/categories/49/1950s-Costumes.php?product=1

And in php fetch the correct data for product 1 and set the meta data:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Answer (score 0):

You should use a canonical URL for each product which will help in two ways.  One with the facebook linter getting the correct og tags.  And two, helping your SEO rankings too.